# jQuery script works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

I have little problem, script works only once, after that I need to refresh page to remove favorite article (script is for that).

```
$("a.fav_no").on('click', function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $(this).load("{$homepage}/user_action.php?action=fav&id="+ id +"").addClass("fav_yes");
        });

$("a.fav_yes").on('click', function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $(this).load("{$homepage}/user_action.php?action=remove_fav&id="+ id +"").removeClass("fav_yes");
        });
```

In console, I get id of article (div) on click after many times on click (so it count) but it doesn't do anything. So I can right now just favorite, to remove from favorites I need to refresh then to click again on link to remove from favorites.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the .on() overload that takes 3 args and is called on the document. Then the events  will remain hooked up as UI elements come and go. No need to re add them every time.

$(document).on("click", "a.offsite", function(){ .....

See the description of .on() here.
 http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I have another problem with this. If is true (if is faved), you can only remove from favorites after that you can't fav again. In case where is false (not faved), everything is all right. Is this problem due jquery or php?
-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing the html that is responsible for catching the events,
you should init those event catchers again.

like this:

```
initEvents() {
     $("a.fav_no").on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).load("{$homepage}/user_action.php?action=fav&id="+ id +"").addClass("fav_yes");
    });

     $("a.fav_yes").on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).load("{$homepage}/user_action.php?action=remove_fav&id="+ id +"").removeClass("fav_yes");
    });

}
```

then you call initEvents on page load,
and than again when html is replaced.