# Captcha Refresh Script Only Works Once

Tags: javascript, php, refresh, captcha

I have a captcha image for form validation and a javascript to refresh the image if it is unreadable for the user.  The script works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox it only works the first time and, after that, though the script runs, the image does not refresh.  the image src includes:

`<?php echo "?rand=" . rand(); ?>`

But despite the fact that the php is working just fine, the refresh is still inoperable.

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441377/jquery-validation-plugin-refresh-captcha-work-only-once), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431416/jquery-script-works-only-once), and have tried many of the suggestions - for example adding and removing `no cache` meta tags, changing the body and head tags to `h:body` and `h:head`.

Many of the suggestions (eg the one [here](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=39998)) describe code situations different from mine (in my case I am using a php-generated image.

Any help will be very appreciated.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function refresh_captcha()
        {
            var img = document.getElementById('captchaimg');
            img.src = 'captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo(rand()); ?>';
            document.getElementById ("captchaimg").src = img.src;
            //alert("some alert.");

        }
```

The page is [here](http://www.syndicateleads.com/workingIndex.php)

Comment: Can you provide js code?

Comment: Check the developer console for errors

Comment: @alexeypalamar Sorry - Meant to add the details, but forgot by the time I got to the end of the post.  Please see edited question.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Been all over the console and firebug, but no errors - it's all working as it should.  I can't find a reason why the image is not refreshing.  I'm sure it will be painfully obvious once I get it, but atm it's baffling.  Most of the other people asking the same (or similar) questions describe it in the same mysterious terms and I have yet to find an answer, or to figure it out myself... :/

Comment: Try to delete this image and add other with new src instead of this.

Comment: @alexeypalamar I tried replacing the innerHTML - is this what you meant?  `<script type="text/javascript">
   function refresh_captcha()
   {
    var img = document.getElementById('captchaimg');
    img.src = 'captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo(rand()); ?>';
    document.getElementById ("captchaDiv").innerHTML = '<img src="captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id="captchaimg" alt="captcha" width="100" tabindex="506">';
    //alert("some alert.");

   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this, random not php, but JS.

```
function refresh_captcha()
    {
        var img = document.getElementById('captchaimg');
        img.src = 'captcha_code_file.php?rand=' + Math.random();
        document.getElementById ("captchaimg").src = img.src;
        //alert("some alert.");
    }
```

Comment: That did the trick!  The only problem is, I figured it was less secure than using php to add randomisation.  This was a point which was brought up a couple of times in other posts...

Comment: > I figured it was less secure than using php to add randomisation. 
No, it isn't maybe you write php code wrong way? Can you provide your php code?

Comment: Sure - `<?php echo(rand()); ?>`

Comment: Try to study examples of already created captchas. As example: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/create_captcha_protection.php I thing you have the a misconception about this mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'm checking the information now.  I had skimmed the information before, but I admit it was only cursory.  I should give it further consideration.